# groovyx.net.http.RESTClient supporting TLSv1.2:

Tags: java

I am supporting an application that uses `groovyx.net.http.RESTClient` for an SMS service to `nexmo.com`. Unfortunately as of now the legacy TLS version 1 and 1.1 are no longer supported. This has an impact on my application.

As I understand it I need to upgrade the app to support version 1.2.

An example of the code usage is...

```
...
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
...

class SmsService {

// settings for nexmo service
private final String apiKey = '********'
private final String apiSecret = '********'
private final String fromUk = '*********'
private final String fromUS = '**********'
private final String regionCode = "GB"
private final String nexmoUrl = 'https://rest.nexmo.com'
private final String nexmoPath = '/sms/json'

def sendSmsMessage(SmsMessageNotification smsMessageNotification){

    def restClient = new RESTClient(nexmoUrl)
     ...
     ...
            def response = restClient.get(path: nexmoPath,
                    headers: [ 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
                    query: [api_key: apiKey, api_secret: apiSecret, from: from,
                            to: phoneNumberString,
                            text: smsMessageNotification.message]
            )
```

How can I upgrade this code to support the new TLS version?

Comment: As your question looks good and well formed, I suggest to update the title to attract more attention.